# Find $c$ which makes $cA$ is an orthogonal projection on $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 2&-1&-1\\-1&2&-1\\-1&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$
$c>0$ and $B=cA$. Find $c$ which makes $B$ is an orthogonal projection on $A$.

Hmmm.....I first find the orthogonal eigenvectors of $A$...
Am I going to the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $B$ is a projection (orthogonal or not), we must have $B^2=B$. And if $B$ is a real symmetric projection matrix, it has to be a orthogonal projection (why?).

Comment: I calculated it now. $c=\frac{1}{3}$, is that right?

Comment: @noname Yes, that is correct.